# Selenium C#: How to get texts after <br> tags

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have seen other posts regarding getting texts after br tags, but none of them helped me getting the text from my web page.

Here is the html snippet where I'm trying to get the text from:

```
.....
<div class="col-md6">
 <ul`enter code here`>
  <p>
    <strong>Rates</strong>
    <br>
     "0.29C/wh 1-Year Fixed"
    <br>
     "0.39C/wh 2-Year Fixed"
    <br>
     "0.59C/wh 3-year Fixed"
    <br>
   </p>
   <p>....</p>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I have tried the following xPath to get the first br tag's text element containing 0.29C:

```
"//*[@id='WebPartWPQ2']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/p[1]/br[1]"
```

But, when I code the following in C# & Selenium I get null return for the text:

```
var productRateElement = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/ [@id='WebPartWPQ2']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/p[1]/br[1]"));

var productRateText = productRateElement.Text;
```

In Chrome browser I can use the same XPath and can locate the text element after the first br tag, but in C# code it returns null.

Hoping to get feedback how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these XPath-1.0 expressions:

```
//div/ul/p/strong/following-sibling::br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

or with the whole path

```
//*[@id='WebPartWPQ2']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/p/strong/following-sibling::br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback zx485. Using the whole path I get the following error in C# code:  "{"invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression \"//*[@id='WebPartWPQ2']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/p/strong/following-sibling::br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]\" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.\n"

Comment: Yes. The result is a `text()` node and not an element. The problem is that the (parent) element of the desired content is `<p>` which contains _all_ text nodes (_and_ the `<br>` elements). So you can use `//div/ul/p` to get the element, but you have to split the text according to your requirements (here it would probably be the second line).

Comment: Thank you zx485. You are right. Targeting the last p tag returns all texts under it. I will work with this string and will try to split it.